# Trying to GET API for Read Sleep Data from google fit but returning 400 Bad request in response

Tags: google-fit

Below is the request I am passing on Google Playground as well as trying through code to fetch Access token and further data. Scope used here : https://www.googleapis.com/auth/fitness.activity.read

```
GET /fitness/v1/users/me/sessions?startTime=2019-12-05T00:00.000Z&endTime=2019-12-17T23:59:59.999Z&activityType=72 HTTP/1.1
Host: www.googleapis.com
Content-length: 0
Authorization: Bearer Auth_code
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your start time is malformed:

```
startTime=2019-12-05T00:00.000Z
```

You need hours, minutes and seconds:

```
startTime=2019-12-05T00:00:00.000Z
```

Request in OAuth playground:

```
GET /fitness/v1/users/me/sessions?startTime=2019-12-05T00:00:00.000Z&endTime=2019-12-17T23:59:59.999Z&activityType=72 HTTP/1.1
Host: www.googleapis.com
Content-length: 0
Authorization: ...
```

Response:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
...
```

Comment: @PayalPandey I'm not sure what data you'd expect to see if you don't have data in that time range.